# How reduce image size in mvc 5

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, html, model-view-controller

i am trying to store image file into database, but want C# code for reduce image size and image quality should be same then how we do it

Comment: What exception?

Comment: i solved that exception and now i changed my question if you have code for reduce an image size then please give me,

Comment: May want to look at FILESTREAM where you still sql-server but the files are stored on the filesystem rather than in the database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403405.aspx

Comment: Could use this ImageProcessor which allows you to manipulate images eg reduce size http://imageprocessor.org/

Comment: I want reduce my HttpPostedBaseFile  in mvc 5 and save it into database, I want that logic, and after save that image, how can i show that list of image s into view